# Where does the cookie-parser middleware for Express.js store its data?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

`express-session` middleware stores the session data server side as stated in the [documentations](https://github.com/expressjs/session) of the said middleware. I was wondering where does `cookie-parser` [middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) stores its data? And another important thing I am intrigued about is the difference between them, when to use what?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies and Sessions are fundamentally different.

Sessions are stored server side and use a unique identifier to provide information about the client issuing the request.

Cookies are files that are stored client side and send client information with the request.

`cookie-parser` does not store any data.  It simply gives your node server the ability to parse the cookies that are coming in with the request easily.

**Edit:** At work at the moment so I don't have a lot of time to explain some of the advantages/disadvantages of each approach.  There have been plenty of things written on the differences online.  If you can't find anything, feel free to drop a comment and I'll try to get on later to answer any questions you may have.